# Spyder debugger: blue arrow disappeared and break points are not taking into account

Tags: python, debugging, spyder

Poblem: When trying to debug a Python script in Spyder, I click the debug button (ctrl + f5) and the code is not executed (with or without breakpoints). I just see that the terminal turns into the debug mode, but the file does not run to the end/breakpoint.
Moreover, when I click any of the blue buttons for the debug panel at the top, **nothing happens**. Also I cannot see the blue arrow that indicates in which line is the file when you are debugging.
Finally, when I click the red button to stop, the script gets executed, and I got all the variables in the Variables panel.

This is what the console displays when I click the debug button:

```
debugfile('C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/1st Semester/ML and 
DM/02450Toolbox_Python/Scripts/ex4_1_5.py', wdir='C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/1st 
Semester/ML and DM/02450Toolbox_Python/Scripts')
> c:\users\usuario\desktop\1st semester\ml and dm\02450toolbox_python\scripts\ex4_1_5.py(3)<module>()
      1 # exercise 4.1.5
      2 
----> 3 from matplotlib.pyplot import (figure, title, subplot, plot, hist, show, 
      4                                xlabel, ylabel, xticks, yticks, colorbar, cm,
      5                                imshow, suptitle)
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) What's your Spyder version? This shouldn't be an issue in our latest version (4.1.5). Also, did you use Anaconda to install Spyder? Using other installation methods can also give you strange problems, like this one.

Comment: Hi Carlos. I update the 4.1.5 version of Spyder and now it is working fine. I had the old version because I had been working with no problems for several months., but suddenly the debugger stopped working.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Nice to know things are working fine for you again.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I installed Spyder without Anaconda in my Mac but none of the debugging features like step into etc work. Is this a bug?